Certain icons missing from Dock after installing Yaru theme on Ubuntu 24.04
After installing Yaru Theme on Ubuntu 24.04, on the Dock where I launch my apps from, certain icons i.e. System Monitor, Document Viewer, Files, and Terminal have been replaced by just a black square.


Which packages did you install and how did you install them?

@mchid, I believe I got it from https://github.com/Jannomag/Yaru-Colors/releases, extracted the files from the Yaru-Colors-1.0.tar.gz file, and ran ./install.sh (if I remember correctly)

My aim was to just get text highlighting in my pdf viewer to go blue. If there is a simpler, Ubuntu supported method to do that, please let me know and I'll start from scratch following the method.

It turns out when Yaru installs its custom icons some icons e.g. terminal are missing and on the dock they appear as a completely black icon. I fixed the issue by uninstalling Yaru but somehow my highlighting stayed the color I chose when installing it (perhaps an error in the options I chose when running ./uninstall.sh).
